# how to get cookies from web browser using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser, session-cookies

I need to get cookies from web browser using jquery means all the cookies from browser which is not generated by my current script/page/domain because i need to access cookies that generated by other websites

Please help me out as i already tried using javascript and jquery but no luck.

thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do? Sounds suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `document.cookie` in javascript. Works only for the same domain. You can't access cookie from different site.

Comment: Security restrictions only allow a web site to retrieve cookies on the same domain (or even sub domain if that was provided in the cookie). document.cookies will only get the current domain's cookies, and it sounds like the submitter is asking to get cookies from other sites (which isn't possible)

Comment: @Neil agree with you . I didnt' noticie that he is looking for the other domain

Comment: Thanks but i already tried document.cookie and you are right its work only for my current script/domain but i need to access cookies that generated by other websites....
is there any solution because browser have all cookies from different websites/scripts than why not we access that?